How can I remove the connection to origin from my local git repository in Visual Studio
I have cloned a remote repository to a local one and would now like to remove the origin.
How can this be done in Visual Studio?

Actually terminal is enough. git remote prune origin

In the terminal choose the git bash terminal and then run this command
git remote show origin 
git remote rm origin

This will remove the origin.

While having the project open in VS, open the Team Explorer and click Settings:

Click Repository Settings

Under Source Control > Git Repository Settings > Remotes:
Find your remote origin and click "Remove"

Click OK, in the pop-up and the origin will now be removed.
